# Apply strip to column of lists in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame `df` with a column named `AD` that contains lists like `[' foo','fo oooo oo   ',' fffo   ','fofofofo']` (note random blankspaces at begining and end of each item in list). How can I apply `strip` function to each element in lists in the whole column?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just rewrite the column with a list with `strip` applied to each element:

```
df['AD'] = [[val.strip() for val in sublist] for sublist in df['AD'].values]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
df['AD'] = df['AD'].map(lambda l: list(map(lambda x: x.strip('o'), l)))
```

or if you only need to remove whitespaces

```
df['AD'] = df['AD'].map(lambda l: list(map(str.strip, l)))
```